# JSON document size exceeds 16MB

Tags: java, mongodb, database

Currently we are planning to replace our database with MongoDB No-SQL database. We are trying to insert our data into MongoDB with JSON document size as more than 16MB. According to MongoDB specification Json document size should not be exceeded 16 MB, In case of more than 16 mb, We have to go for GridFS.

Here We are facing 2 problems:
1) The document size is not always more than 16MB. Some times it will exceed 16MB.(Even for less than 16 MB also, we forced to use GridFS)

2) The retrieval from GridFS is not easy as fetching from normal Collection and fetching of particular key is giving only value({"Id": "123656"} fetch("Id") -> "123656" but we should get "Id": "123656"). It might effect the performance.

Please correct me if i am wrong. AM I really following the proper procedure.

Could any body please let me know what is the better approach.